# Plotting a different color for each bin in a histogram (Matplotlib)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
Favorite B | Q1
________________
McDonalds  | 5
BurgerKing | 6
KFC        | 3
Brand4     | 2
```

i am plotting histograms out of it:

```
x=pd.Series(df["Q1"])
result = plt.hist(x, bins=7, color='c', edgecolor='k', alpha=0.65)
plt.axvline(x.mean(), color='k', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=1)

min_ylim, max_ylim = plt.ylim()
plt.text(x.mean()*1.1, max_ylim*0.9, 'Mean: {:.2f}'.format(x.mean()))
plt.title(str(i))
```

I want a different color for each bin.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (based on [this example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pyplots/pyplot_text.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pyplots-pyplot-text-py)):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(0)

mu, sigma = 100, 15
x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(10000)

colors = ['#1f77b4', '#ff7f0e', '#2ca02c', '#d62728', '#9467bd', '#8c564b', '#e377c2', '#7f7f7f', '#bcbd22', '#17becf']

n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, bins=len(colors))

# adapt the color of each patch
for c, p in zip(colors, patches):
    p.set_facecolor(c)

plt.show()
```

[image: histogram with differently colored bars]